# How do I upgrade items such as the DAGON that say Upgradable

Tags: dota-2

[image]

Some items such as the Dagon (pictured) are upgradeable.

How do I upgrade it? I tried purchasing another one, but then I just had 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to buy another **recipe** to upgrade the corresponding item.

[image: Dagon]

Just go up the item hierarchy, shift-click, and the recipe (or anything that you need to finish the item) will appear in the quick buy slot.

To see how many levels of upgrades an item has, just keep going up. Alternatively, you can search the item's name and all its different levels will be listed as search results.

Comment: And to buy the recipe I assume I'd click the item, then in the bottom bit where it shows the constitute items I click the recipe that's shown there? Or is there an easier way of getting to the recipe?

Answer (score 1):

Dont buy the full item, just buy another recipe. You can access it buy left clicking on the item on the shop > it show all the components of the items then > right click on the scroll and there you go, Dagon level 2

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of knowing how many upgrades I can give it?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett For the Dagon you can go up to level 5, you can have further explanation on the DotA 2 wiki => http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Items

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Dagon goes to 5, Necronomicon goes to 3. Those are the only upgradable items, currently.

Comment: @Decency diffusal go to level 2

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answers already given, some items with charges can be recharged by buying another recipe.
Drums of endurance can be replenished indefinitely by just buying another recipe.  This only works if the item displays charges on it and does not get upgraded (so only applies to drums at the moment), it does not work on a BKB or Diffusal Blade level 2, but upgrading a Diffusal Blade level 1 will still replenish the charges.

Answer (score 1):

The general answer to this query is to drag the item to the shop window (not quick buy). This will show you all the items your item can lead to. i.e. the level 1 Dagon can lead to the level 2 Dagon. It will show you what you need for this (the recipe). If you drag the level 2 Dagon to the quick buy window then the items you needed will be available for quick buy.